# How to handle multiple bambooinstances with one bamboo.yaml

Tags: yaml, bamboo

I have a bamboo.yaml (same project) which is used on 2 diffrent Bambooservers - this is needed (cause of staging concept and other stufff)

The buildjobs differ a bit on those bambooinstances, i could solve this by using global-variables and conditional Task.
Like this:

```
   tasks:
    - maven:
        executable: Maven 3.6.3
        jdk: JDK 11.0.2
        goal: |-
          clean install -s settings.xml
        environment: BUILD_USER=${bamboo.hpf_bamboo_user} BUILD_PWD=${bamboo.hpf_bamboo_password}
        conditions:
          - variable:
              equals:
                bamboo_instance: devstack
    - maven:
        executable: Maven 3.6.3
        jdk: JDK 11.0.2
        goal: |-
          clean deploy -s settings.xml
        environment: BUILD_USER=${bamboo.hpf_bamboo_user} BUILD_PWD=${bamboo.hpf_bamboo_password}
        conditions:
          - variable:
              equals:
                bamboo_instance: ci
```

The group which should have permissions on the job has diffrent names on the bambooinstances too,
but i cant use variables on permissions.

```
plan-permissions:
  - users: []
    groups: ${bamboo.devgroup}
```

This will return the error "no group '${bamboo.devgroup}'"

Has anyone a idea how i could solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: Found a Solution

its possible to define the bamboo-server name in the yaml - bamboo will skip the configurations which have another servername as itself :)

```
server-name: 'bambooservername'
```